# how to remove last symbols?

Tags: java, string

```
List<String> solList = new ArrayList<String>( );
solList.add( "num1" );
solList.add( "num2" );

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for ( String a : solList )
{
result.append( a ).append( ", " );
}

String withoutLastComma = result.substring( 0, result.length( ) - ", 
".length( ) );
System.err.println( withoutLastComma );
```

I want remove last comma,I use substring,how can I become  better this code?

use string utility methods such as "StringUtil.join" to concatenate elements in an array or a collection object. Consult the "StringUtil API's StringUtil.join" entry.

For example:
  `StringUtils.join(["e", "f", "g"], "--")  // => "e--f--g`

Comment: If you just want to add comma's, use a simple for loop with length -2

Comment: You can do everything with [`String.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

Comment: You can just do `result.setLength(result.length() - 1)`. Or, rather than using the simple `for` loop, you can get the `solList.iterator()` and loop over it "manually" (`while (iterator.hasNext()) { ...`), and that lets you check within the loop whether there's a next element -- so you can just not add that comma to begin with, if you're at the last element. (Or, as ajb pointed out, use the library call that does this for you.)

Comment: TO remove last `, `, do `result.delete(result.length()-2,result.length());`

Comment: @JaySmith Note that he appended two characters between each element--comma and space--so your code will remove the last space but not the comma.

Comment: Have a look at `StringJoiner` as an alternative to `StringBuilder` for this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is one of the way you can get comma separated list:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int size = 0;
if(solList!=null && (size=solList.size())>0)
{
   result.append(solList.get(0));
   for ( int i=1;i<size;i++ )
   {
        result.append( ", " ).append(solList.get(i));
    }
 }
```

Comment: The only flaw is that it doesn't handle empty lists.

Comment: Thanx for your comments

Comment: Patch it with an `if (!solList.isEmpty())`, and make it work for empty lists. It is not a very beautiful solution though but it works.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this.  Java 8 already provides a `join` method in `String` that will join strings in a list or array with a fixed string between each pair of elements.

Here's another way.  I'm including this as an answer because it's a useful idiom in other array/list traversal cases not necessarily involving strings and separators:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for ( String a : solList )
{
    if (!first) {
        result.append(", ");
    }
    result.append(a);
    first = false;
}
```

I wouldn't use it here, but this pattern comes up in many contexts.

This basically works the same way as denis's answer, just expressed in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 0):

**List to Comma-separated String** [Using java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)
See the [String.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/package-summary.html)

**Logic 1:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestApp2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");

        String result = String.join(",", list);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

OutPut:

```
A,B,C,D
```

**Logic 2:**

A StringJoiner may be employed to create formatted output from a Stream using Collectors.joining(CharSequence). For example:

```
 List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
 String commaSeparatedNumbers = numbers.stream()
     .map(i -> i.toString())
     .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

OutPut:

```
1,2,3,4
```